# ListBox items need to occupy entire height of the Grid row

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem

In my WPF application I have a `ListBox` placed in `Grid` row. I want the list items to occupy the height of the row irrespective of how many items are there in the list. So when there is only one item in the list, it should be of the height of that row. If there are two items in the list, they both should together occupy the total height of the row. Currently when there is one item in the list, its height becomes smaller than the row height.

My XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- there are other controls in grid row 0, 1 and 2 -->

    <ListBox x:Name="CustomerListBox" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding CustomersCollection}"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <!--<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                    <UniformGrid Columns="1" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>-->

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <uiView:CustomerUserControl Margin="0.5,0,0,-10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

When I uncomment the `ItemsPanelTemplate` portion, it works as expected due to UniformGrid placed in items panel, but I don't want to use ItemsPanelTemplate for this ListBox due to some other reasons. Is there any way I can make the items occupy entire height of the grid row without using the Uniform Grid and ItemsPanelTemplate?

Comment: Have you considered an itemscontrol in a viewbox?

Comment: @Andy - I will check it and give a try.. thanks for suggestion!  +1

Comment: One of the msdn forums also suggesting to implement custom height converter using multi value converter.. Will try that as well

Comment: I'd try the viewbox first. Two tags and you're done. You'd still need something to scale the content if you calculate height.

Comment: A `UniformGrid` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` really is the easiest way I can think of. Could you explain the reason you can't use that?

Comment: @KeithStein - I have implemented custom data virtualization for the items source data behind the scene. When I implement any kind of ItemsPanelTemplate, the indexer is not fired when user scrolls the list. In fact all the items in the list get loaded initially in the memory which is not expected from data virtualization. If I remove template, it starts working. May be because the template might be using some internal array of items which calls all index change initially at a time. Reference : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization

Comment: @Andy - I am a beginner in WPF, but if if I am not wrong, ItemsControl is not having the concept of SelectedIndex and selection of its items and related events as such. In my application, there is high level of interaction by selecting the items manually as well as automatically through code depending on business logic.